# Avoid using 'at' twice

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I was wondering if there is a better way of saying the following sentence:

> I received the ABC scholarship **at** the PQR center **at** the University of Education.

I have seen this in many places, but I was hoping to have a better way if possible.

Comment: You could use _of_ instead of the second _at_. _The ABC Scholarship at the PQR Center **of** the University of Wherever_.

Comment: Or could use possessive, *The ABC Scholarship at Whatever University's PQR Center*.  Choice depends in part on what you want to emphasize

Comment: or just *at the PQR center, University of Education.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thought that occurred to me was as suggested by John Lawler in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75296/using-at-twice-to-address-subset-programs-centers#comment146153_75296):

> I received the ABC scholarship at the PQR center **of** the University of Education.

That would eliminate the repeated *at*.  Another option you have (and this was suggested by jwpat7 [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75296/using-at-twice-to-address-subset-programs-centers#comment146154_75296)) is to say:

> I received the ABC scholarship at the University's PQR center.

Note that it doesn't work as well with a name like *University of Education*; I would not suggest *I received the ABC scholarship at the University of Education's PQR center*.

Comment: Isn't the correct procedure to promote others' suggestions to a Community Wiki answer?